# use curl in windows (xampp)

Tags: php, curl

I use following line to get status.

> $curl_cmd = "/usr/bin/curl -k -d \"$post_data\" $url 2>/dev/null";

now, this is working perfectly in my server.
Quetion is, how to write this line so it is working in my local?currently it is not working in my local beacause there is no  such `usr/bin` directory.so how to solve  it?
How to convert this line for windows?
 I use xampp in  windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can find the file n the xampp\php-Folder (Windows) or in the /etc-Folder (in the Xampp/Lampp-Folder). It can be edited using a normal Text-Editor.
```

php.ini and you will find the curl in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
go to C:\xampp\php\php.ini  //your xampp location
```

in php.ini

```
just remove ";" from ";extension=php_curl.dll" line.
```

and restart apache

Comment: nope....no error.i use that line to get status from the third party(like api).which working perfectlly in server.but not in my local.soquetion is how  to convert that line so it is work in windows?